# NoSuchMethodError in apache camel java

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I ran the following code:

```
package com.dinesh.example4;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
//import org.apache.camel.support.HeaderFilterStrategyComponent;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Component;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
//import org.apache.camel.impl.*;

public class FileToActiveMQ {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        context.addComponent("jms",JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
              from("file:input_box?noop=true")
                .to("activemq:queue:my_queue");
                }
        });
        while(true)
        context.start();
        }
}
```

for transforming data from input_box folder to activemq.

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.impl.HeaderFilterStrategyComponent.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.<init>(JmsComponent.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.<init>(JmsComponent.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.jmsComponent(JmsComponent.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(JmsComponent.java:127)
    at com.dinesh.example4.FileToActiveMQ.main(FileToActiveMQ.java:18)
```

Here 18 th line in above code:
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dinesh</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-application1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.4</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you have mixed versions of Camel JARs on your classpath. Make sure to use the same version only.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.4</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.24.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 3):

According to your POM you mix 3 different Camel versions: 2.14.4, 2.24.0 and 3.0.0.

You have to use the same version for all Camel components, as @claus-ibsen already commented.

Do it for example like the example below (with properties for the framework versions and use it in all its dependencies).

However, as Sneharghya already answered, Camel 2.x has no `camel-activemq` but instead can use the dependency `activemq-camel` of ActiveMQ.

Therefore the POM should look like this. But I think the Camel version can vary.

```
<properties>
    <amq.version>5.15.4</amq.version>     
    <camel.version>2.19.5</camel.version> 
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    <version>${amq.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also use [Maven dependencyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management).

Comment: How to get the same version?Please tell,bec' I am new to apache camel framework.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer. It is actually not a Camel but a Maven issue

Comment: After updating another error is coming,but for above pom.xml  activemq version is different from other 2 dependencies.so i updated accordingly.now following error is coming:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent.getMessageCreatedStrategy()Lorg/apache/camel/component/jms/MessageCreatedStrategy; at context.start(); in the above code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the new `camel-activemq` component. I fixed my answer, but the `NoSuchMethodError` is still a mixed version problem

Answer (score 1):

`camel-activemq` is not available for versions older than 3.0.
If you want to keep using camel 2.24.3, then remove the `camel-activemq` dependency from your pom file and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    <version>5.15.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: After updating as above, now the following error is coming.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent.getMessageCreatedStrategy()Lorg/apache/camel/component/jms/MessageCreatedStrategy;, at context.start().

Comment: Actually I am using activemq version 5.15.4, for this please tell me the version of camel core.in maven pom.xml.

Comment: Use activemq-camel version 5.15.4. Camel 2.24.3 will be fine!

Comment: No, it's not working, again exception is coming.for me .Activemq:5.8.0 ,camel core-2.12.1 there is no errors(on runtime also).But My Activemq version is 5.15.4 so output is not coming.So Please tell for Activemq 5.15.4, what is the exact version of camel core?in maven pom.

Comment: Try with camel 2.19.5

Comment: still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Update the class**
There are two issues.

- One you were registering your component in one name `jms` and send the message to different component `activemq`. They should be same.
- You were doing a while loop and instead the while loop starting the context many times.

```
public class FileToActiveMQ {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    context.addComponent("activemq", 
          JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("file:input_box?noop=true")
        .to("activemq:queue:my_queue");
      }
    });
   context.start();
   while(true) {
     Thread.sleep(10000);
   }

  }
}
```

**2. Replace the dependencies in pom as follows:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
      <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.7</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi, i want to use activemq only.Please tell the code.bec' of these example i have downloaded activemq from internet and i ran it.

Comment: Now I tried it. there is no runtime errors/exceptions.but output is not coming.i have input_box folder in my project explorer, i am creating 1 text file and i have to go to activemq server(http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp),here the file is not populating.

Comment: File consumed message keep on coming,i think some problem with activemq.not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216783/discussion-between-devi-george-and-kavithakaran-kanapathippillai).